Select From 2 tables in mySQL step by step
I have 2 tables like this :
Table A: 
-----------------------------------------------
ProductID       Dis_Sale      Discount
-----------------------------------------------
1                true           10%
2                true           5%
3                false          0%
...



Table B :
-----------------------------------------------
ProducID       Customer        Discount
-----------------------------------------------
1                Sam               20%
1                John              15%
...

Now I want to search in tables and return value with this conditions :
example for customer : Sam
if Table A > productID = 1 and Dis_Sale = true then search in Table B and if ProductID = 1 and Customer = 'Sam' then return Discount from Table B
result : 20%
example for customer : Bob
if Table A > ProductID = 2  and Dis_Sale = true then search in Table B and if ProductID = 2 and Customer = 'Bob' then return Discount from Table B
( in this case Bob is not in Table B so back to Table A and return Discount from Table A )
result : 5%
example for customer : John
if Table A > ProductID = 3  and Dis_Sale = true then search in Table B and if ProductID = 3 and Customer = 'John' then return Discount from Table B
( in this case Dis_Sale = false so don't search in Table B and return 0)
result : 0%
What is MySQL select code for these conditions?

Use SQL JOIN queries for this.

How to ask homework question and Open letter to students with homework problems

You can use SQL JOIN for this. Simple example would be,
SELECT TA.ProductId, TA.DIS_Sale, TA.Discount, TB.Customer, TB.Discount
FROM A as TA 
JOIN B as TB 
ON TA.ProductId = TB.ProductId

However, the logic you mentioned in the question is more like a business logic. So, I suggest you can use a method to determine these different outcomes based a simple if-else condition.
